# "Word of the Day" Screensaver without Words?

Tags: macos, screensaver, customization

Using Onyx I have set the Word of the Day screensaver as my desktop.

The shimmering blue water effect is wonderful but I am distracted by the words flying through the screen and the fade to black every 30 seconds.

How can I disable the word effects and shift to black so the screensaver is the shimmering blue water by itself?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an edited version. This is just the backdrop — I've removed the text scrolling, the dictionary result and the keyboard controls.

[image]

- [georgegarside.com/o/se/Word of the Day Background.qtz](https://georgegarside.com/o/se/Word%20of%20the%20Day%20Background.qtz)

Place this in **~/Library/Screen Savers** and restart System Preferences, then select it from the list.